# R sum values in two columns based on two index columns leaving NA values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with the number of suicides and population broken down by age group for each year and country, including NA values for some countries/years.

I would like to sum the number of suicides and populations across age groups for each year and country but leave NA if a given country has no data for a given year.

Input would look like:

```
country = c("Albania", "Albania", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia")
year = c("1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1992", "1992"
suicides_no = c(NA, NA, 5, 3, 12, 9)
population = c(100, 200, 50, 75, 250, 300)
df = data.frame(country, year, suicides_no, population
```

and the output columns would be:

```
country year suicides_no population
Albania 1991 NA          300
Croatia 1991 8           125
Croatia 1992 21          550
```

Answer (score 0):

Groupby country, year and run a summary of groups, like below

```
  df %>% 
group_by(country,year) %>% 
summarize(suicides_no_sum = sum(suicides_no), population_sum = sum(population))
```

Should give:

```
 country year  suicides_no_sum population_sum
  <chr>   <chr>           <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Albania 1991               NA            300
2 Croatia 1991                8            125
3 Croatia 1992               21            550
```

Comment: Hi thanks Jinesh. This is giving me just one row output that says NA in suicide_no and a huge number in population. Also how do I save this into my existing dataframe?

Comment: @engelbrekt Just assign the result to ur dataframe , df= df %>% group_by......

Comment: Hey, that didn't work my dataframe is now just 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ suicides_no_sum: num NA
 $ population_sum : num 975

Answer (score 0):

Using across function:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(country, year) %>% summarise(across(suicides_no:population, sum))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'country' (override with `.groups` argument)
df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   country [2]
  country year  suicides_no population
  <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Albania 1991           NA        300
2 Croatia 1991            8        125
3 Croatia 1992           21        550
```